multi-dimensional vector read issue causing two errors
Goal:
My goal is to retrieve two lines of numerical data from a five/six -dimension vector and place that data into a two-dimension vector, one value at a time.
Some might assume this ought to be a very simple build or simple situation.
But in the real world we don't get to cherry pick our favorite data structures. In the real world (after class-time is over), there's always going to be situations where you have data strutures with a multitude of dimensions and lots of hairy stuff going on.
If I was trying to track all of the variables that go on at a local zoo during COVID (or something even scarier), it is an easy assumption to make, their admin would want to put digital markers on all the animals, all of the possible visitors and foreign animals/insects.
Every animal and person has a whole slew of categories. Height, weight, size, breeding specifics, species, sub-species and their likelihood of getting diseases because of X. Then all of the data for the visitors and the animals & insects that don't belong there (like mosquitoes and birds that fly overhead).
That's a massive amount of data with multiple layers and thus a massive amount of dimensions that we have to deal with.
Big Data isn't just about size. It's about the management of complex, multi-layered data structures.
Any given data structure has to match the layers of data coming in and how it's being used.
Looking ahead, I know that I will need to understand large, hairy data structural schemes and make them work. In preparation, I want to improve my muscle memory for the proper design of convoluted data-structures, before I begin using algorithms and numerical modeling techniques.
Errors:
Both errors are being called from MS VS2019, inside the system.cpp file for the system class.
first error: C++ expression must have class type but it has type
second error: C++ expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type
While I have taken both of those errors and googled them and looked at a lot of the automated results, I am NOT using a pointer inside the system class, nor has this situation have anything to do with a convoluted constructor, an enum or special class types.
Again, my goal is to retrieve two lines of numerical data from a five/six -dimension vector and place that data into a two-dimension vector, one value at a time. there are no other classes nor pointers.
Note: Yes, I could copy part of that vector into another vector (one dimension at a time), but I do not feel I am ready for that challange. I am trying to learn the simpliest of methods, first.
Code:
The system.h file for system class.
#ifndef _SYSTEM_IDEL_H
#define _SYSTEM_IDEL_H

#include <vector>

class System
{
public:
    // constructor
    System();

    void Update();

    std::vector<std::vector<int>>  get_vec_int() { return vec_output_int; }

private:

    int top = 0;
    int upper = 0;
    int middle = 0;
    int bottom = 0;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec_output_int; // two dimensions

    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>>> vec_value // five dimensions
    { // top
        { // upper
            { // middle
                { // bottom
                    // data_type
                    { 1, 0, 0, 9, 0 },
                    { 0, 0, 7, 0, 1 }
                },
                { // bottom
                    // data_type
                    { 1, 1, 5, 0, 0 },
                    { 0, 2, 0, 7, 3 }
                },
            }
        }
    };
};
#endif

The system.cpp file for system class.
#include "system.h"

System::System() {}

void System::Update()
{
    for (int data_type = 0; data_type < vec_value[top][upper][middle][bottom].size(); data_type++)
    {
        vec_output_int.emplace_back();

        // First Error is being called from a misuse of .size() the error resolves itself when I remove the .size().
        // But as you might imagine, removing .size() will not solve anything becasuse '<' has to have a value that reps the length of the vector at the 'data_type' dimension.
        for (int var_data = 0; var_data < vec_value[top][upper][middle][bottom][data_type].size(); var_data++)
        {
            // Second Error is being called from a missuse of [var_data] and this is where I get even more lost.
            // While vec_value only has five dimensions, the fifth dimension appears to have another dimension within it.
            vec_output_int[data_type].push_back(vec_value[top][upper][middle][bottom][data_type][var_data]);
        }
    }
}

Main of messy_for_loop_04.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "system.h"

std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec_output_value;

System* system;

int main()
{
    system = new System();

    vec_output_value = system->get_vec_int(); // 2 sets of values (5 each)
    
    for (int data_type = 0; data_type < vec_output_value.size(); data_type++)
    {
        for (int var_data = 0; var_data < vec_output_value[data_type].size(); var_data++)
        {
            std::cout << "\n" + vec_output_value[data_type][var_data];
        }
    }
}

Edited:

changed header for system.h file.


Totally unrelated note: _SYSTEM_H is an illegal identifier. Breaking these rules doesn't bite all that often, but when it does, it bites HARD.

vec_value[top][upper][middle][bottom][data_type] is an int. You are trying to call size() on it; that doesn't make sense. vec_value has 5 dimensions, and you've specified 5 indices. There's nothing deeper to iterate over.

Note a global variable system, as in System* system;, will collide with the library function system. Since you can't always control what headers are included by other headers, you can't guarantee whether or not system is being defined twice in the same scope. Globals suck anyway, they dramatically complicate debugging by adding potential side effects to everything you do, so I'd solve this problem by finding a way to eliminate the global variable, but you can easily rename the variable to eliminate the possibility of collisions.

Handy trick: If you don't understand a compiler diagnostic, throw the code at another compiler or two and see if they describe the problem better. Eg: https://godbolt.org/z/ascjsGz8T

"there's always going to be situations where you have data structures with a multitude of dimensions". There are generally organized in classes, not as big row matrix.

thank you for the comments about system. I only uses that label for a quick name, not that I would (or do) use it for actual, real projects. this is just quick and dirty labeling to get this error fixed,

thank you user4581301. Ialways forget about those online compliers!

promblem still stands, if you look to the vector vec_value[top][upper][middle][bottom][data_type]

Your "question" looks more like a dissertation than a question. Skipping down to the "Errors:" part, it looks like you are asking about a simple syntax error? (Well, two syntax errors, but there is a limit of one question per question.) How is the "Goal:" section relevant for a syntax question? Forget what you are working on, think abstractly, reduce your code to a [mre] (maybe half a dozen lines), and focus your question on that.

@maninthemiddle "promblem still stands, if you look to the vector vec_value[top][upper][middle][bottom][data_type]" -- That's not a vector. You start with vec_value, which is a five-dimensional vector of int. Specifying top gives a four-dimensional vector. Further specifying upper gives a three-dimensional vector. Further specifying middle gives a two-dimensional vector. Further specifying bottom gives a one-dimensional vector. Further specifying data_type gives an element, not a vector. Your compiler is correct to complain.

@user4581301  System* system;  <--- that is a pointer, this is C++.
Jarod42 wow I want you to go to your boss and ask that person if they want you to make an inifinite number of child classes for every single possible characterization for the scope of what for your employer is automating.
there has to be a line drawn somewhere and data fills the blank.
problem still stands, if you look at the system.h and inspect the vector vec_value you will see two rows inside that 5th dimension.
Right now: a 5th dimension with two rows inside of it is the issue. come on jedi focus.

@maninthemiddle "if you look at the system.h and inspect the vector vec_value you will see two rows inside that 5th dimension." -- Nope. I do not see that. Should we check your counting skills? First dimension: { // top, second dimension: { // upper, third dimension: { // middle, fourth dimension: { // bottom (with two rows inside it), and fifth dimension: { 1, 0, 0, 9, 0 }. Don't let yourself get confused by your inconsistent formatting of the labels. The first four labels are after an opening brace, the fifth is before.

Yep, it is a pointer, but it has the same name as a C library function, and that leads to trouble. You might not be seeing this trouble, but all three of the compilers I threw your code at above tripped over it so it's not too far away from becoming a problem for you.

To solve the problem in the title
Get the fifth dimension  size : vec_value[top][upper][middle][bottom].size().
Push_back the value:  vec_value[top][upper][middle][bottom][var_data].
  for (int var_data = 0; var_data < vec_value[top][upper][middle][bottom].size(); var_data++)
   {
       vec_output_int[data_type].push_back(vec_value[top][upper][middle][bottom][var_data]);
   }


Other problems:

system->Update(); is not called in main():

Global pointer system is conflict with  stdlib function:
_DCRTIMP int __cdecl system(
In_opt_z char const* _Command
);.


Declare   System* system; in main().

You are trying to print  string and  number at the same time.
std::cout << "\n" + vec_output_value[data_type][var_data];


instead:
 for (int data_type = 0; data_type < vec_output_value.size(); data_type++)
 {
     for (int var_data = 0; var_data < vec_output_value[data_type].size(); var_data++)
     {
         std::cout << vec_output_value[data_type][var_data] <<" " ;
     }
     std::cout << "\n";
 }


turned a five dimension vector into a six dimension vector. errors vanished. done. mind you I could have spent another minute to make a better working example, but oh well, it was for naught, anyhow. i solved in my sleep, last night, literally.
